# Interactivity w/ Standard-In via pseudo-runloop blocks program execution

Tags: c, cocoa

I have created a simple graphical cocoa application that has various function that affect an `NSImageView`.  I want to see the effects of these functions quickly so I have constructed the following code:

```
void ABRUNLOOP();


void func1() {
   printf("func1 \n");
   ABRUNLOOP();
}

void func2() {
   printf("func2 \n");
   ABRUNLOOP();
}


void ABRUNLOOP() {


   int i;
   scanf("%d", &i);

   if (i == 1) {
      func1();
   } else if ( i == 2) {
      func2();
   } else {
      printf("not a valid command \n");
      ABRUNLOOP();
   }

}
```

This has the effect of calling functions `func1()` and `func2()` (or an arbitrary number of functions I wish to map to integer values entered via the console).  The problem is that the continuous execution of the "runloop" is to block other program execution.  Specifically, called `ABRUNLOOP()` in `viewDidLoad:` prevents the view from ever rendering.  Secondly, if I could somehow insert this Runloop code after the view was rendered, it would prevent it from rendering again.  Given that I want this type of simple interface (entering ints to call functions and see their effects quickly), how can I refactor this so that it does not stall (i assume) the main runloop of this Cocoa Application?

Comment: Recursion (a function that calls itself, directly or *indirectly*) is just a way or looping. In this case you don't have any end condition on the loop, or the recursion, meaning you will sooner or later run out of stack and the program will crash. Don't use recursion here, use loops (why else did you name the function `ABRUNLOOP`?)

Comment: Sure, that solves the problem of stack depth.  But, main runloop execution is still interrupted by this sequence of execution, no?  So it occurred to me to throw this entire Recursion (now iteration) into a background queue with GCD and push to the main queue whenever one of the relevant graphics-affecting functions is called, and then back onto the background.  Is there a better way?

Comment: But the problem isn't with the infinite recursion (or loops which are better here), it's with you having an infinite loop (one way or another) in a program using an evenloop. If you don't process events in your own loop they will never be dispatched. If you want to handle UI events you need to find some other way of getting console input, or process the even queue yourself some way. And what's worse is that you are using a *blocking function* (`scanf` blocks until user presses the enter key), prohibiting even processing even further.

Comment: My thinking was I need the infinite loop to be able to intercept standard-in at arbitrary times.  If this basic method of constantly accepting keyboard input via `scanf` fundamentally blocks all process execution, than how can I implement this behavior.  E.g. I type in "1" into console and some function of my choosing executes.

Comment: actually, THIS works provided it is executed on background-queue via GCD..

while (true) {
      
      
      if (i == 1) {
         
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self func1];
         });
         
         
      } else if ( i == 2) {
         
         dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self func2];
         });
         
         
      } else {
         printf("not a valid command \n");
      }
      
      
      scanf("%d", &i);
   }